# How to include short signals in a Long only strategy on tradingview?

Tags: pine-script

How to include short signals in a Long only strategy on tradingview?

I have a Tradingview strategy which gives only long/Buy signals as per matching conditions. I also need it to generate short signals when the conditions are suitable. How do I do it?

```
strategy("Varun scalp", shorttitle="Varun scalp", overlay=true)
timeframe = input('3')
box = input('Traditional')
boxsize = input(5, type=float)
reversal = input(1)
pnf = pointfigure(tickerid, 'close', box, boxsize, reversal)
pnf_open= security(pnf, timeframe , open)
pnf_close= security(pnf, timeframe , close)
p1 = plot(pnf_open, title="pnf_open", color=green)
p2 = plot(pnf_close,  title="pnf_close",color=maroon)
base = pnf_close> pnf_open? pnf_close: pnf_open
p0 = plot(base, title="base", color=gray)
fill(p0, p2, color=green, transp=70)
fill(p0, p1, color=maroon, transp=70)
entry() => (base > pnf_close)
exit() => (base > pnf_open)
alertcondition(entry(), title='buy', message='buy!')
alertcondition(exit(), title='sell', message='sell!')
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)
strategy.entry("Long", long=true, when=entry())
strategy.entry("close", false, when=exit())
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `long` parameter of `strategy.entry()` to `false`.

> long (bool) A required parameter. Market position direction: 'true' or
> 'strategy.long' is for long, 'false' or 'strategy.short' is for short.

Answer (score 0):

to elaborate on Vitruvius' answer, you want to include those in addition to what you already have.  So the end of your code will look like this - which should be noted that it will reverse long and shorts back and forth OR close the long or short strategy, whicher happens first.

first define your entry and exit conditions outside of the strategy statement.

```
entry=(whatever your entry logic is)
exit=(whatever your exit logic is)
shortentry=(whatever your entry logic is)
shortexit=(short exit logic)
strategy.entry("Long", long=true, when=entry)
strategy.entry("Short", long=false, when=shortentry)
strategy.close("close long", when=exit)
strategy.entry("close short", when=shortexit)
```